# Confusion matrix in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am trying to create a confusion matrix in python. However as you can see in the image below, my class labels arent matching up with each other. I essentially want the y axis to start with *Tshirt/Top* and end with *Ankle Boots*. This is my code:

```
test_labels = test_labels.argmax(axis=1)
predictions = predictions.argmax(axis=1)
cm = confusion_matrix(test_labels, predictions)

plt.setp(ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(class_names), rotation=90, horizontalalignment='right')
plt.setp(ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(class_names), rotation=360, horizontalalignment='right')
```

[image]

I am new to python so im not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried reversing your `y` axis?

Comment: Try replacing rotation=360 with rotation=180

Comment: i have already played around with the rotation, it just changes the text label orientation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this before last 2 lines:

```
class_names = class_names[::-1]
```

Looks like a reversed list is all you need?

Comment: doing this after the first plt.setp line fixed it, thanks!!